# How to edit the default spartacus breakpoints

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In Spartacus, I see this [breakpoint.service.ts](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/blob/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/layout/breakpoint/breakpoint.service.ts)
But may I know how to override or create a custom set of breakpoints?
It doesn't seem to include any `set` method (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could override the service, the intend is that you configure the breakpoints, using the typed `LayoutConfig`. You can configure one or multiple breakpoints using the `ConfigModule`:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  breakpoints: {
    xs: 576,
    sm: 768,
    md: 1024,
    lg: 1200
  },
} as LayoutConfig)
```

The typescript configuration is used to control the DOM. TO control the CSS, you need to configure the breakpoints in the CSS, using the scss `$grid-breakpoints` variable.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px,
  xl: 1200px,
) !default;
```

Unfortunately, those configurations are a bit out of sync: in CSS, you specify the max value for the breakpoint, where as in typescript you specify the min value.